# How to change HTML of Menu in Magento 2.4.2 Claue Theme?

Tags: magento2, category, theme, menu, sub-categories

I want to change some HTML in Magento 2.4.2 Claue theme.

Like when I add 12 subcategory the design is not good it will add subcategory one below other so it will not looking good. I want to add counter value to make it different ul after some subcategory and need to add some classes in that ul and li.
So, I want to change in file but when I search it will show three files and all are in cache folder.

```
app/code/MGS/Mmegamenu/view/frontend/templates/cache/top_menu.phtml
app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/MGS_Mmegamenu/templates/cache/top_menu.phtml
```

So need to know how to change that HTML.

Comment: You can enable the template path hints to see what template is used: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/template-path-hints.html

Comment: Thanks for your response @Marius i have checked that and it will used Mega Menu and the data will be fetched from getMenuCacheHtml function which is a cache and get data from Database tabel mgs_megamenu_cache table but i want to change it before it will save in the db will you please help.

Comment: sorry, I have no experience with that extension

Comment: Okk no problem thanks for the help for template path link.

Comment: If I understand the the goal completely, it sure sounds like you can accomplish it just using CSS (i.e. with :nth-child, etc.)